# IF IE neglect/hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have page like this

```
<html>
<head>

<div id="container">
Hello, this is NON-IE content.
</div>

</head>
</html>
```

What I want is to **Stop** Internet Explorer **[ IE ]** from **loading OR Neglecting** `<div id="container">` & **allow** all **other browsers** to **load** It.

Don't want to use `<!--[if IE 7]>`.

Looking for **Javascript** to work with.

How Can I achieve this ?

Thanks

- Mandar

Comment: Why do you want to use something complicated that a significant number of users turn off instead of conditional comments (which are simple and reliable)?

Comment: @david : What you are saying is true but due to some limitations on my page area I can't Use it..

Comment: -1 browser sniffing is discouraged. Aside from that <!--[if IE 7]> is your best bet. Browsers lie, jQuery is only guessing.. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: @galambalazs - Downvoting is typically used on questions what are poorly-written, off-topic, too vague, etc. - not when you don't agree with it.

Comment: you are no SO god, nor do you know how **awful practice** was asked here. Every person has the **free right** to downvote to **ensure quality**, express opinion. Maybe you would like communism better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For users that don't want to use jQuery, you can simply do:

```
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) {
    alert('This is Internet Explorer!');
}
```

http://devoracles.com/the-best-method-to-check-for-internet-explorer-in-javascript

> What we see up there? I declared a new
>   variable, called IE, which has the
>   value a comment block followed by
>   ‘false‘. The above variable will be
>   understood by IE: var IE = !false,
>   because Internet Explorer uses JScript
>   — a Javascript-like dialect of the
>   standard ECMAScript — instead of
>   Javascript which is used by all the
>   other browsers. JScript can parse the
>   comments, just like Internet Explorer
>   (see conditional HTML comments post).
>   This is a unique feature of IE, none
>   of the other browsers can do it, so
>   Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, all
>   will understand the above declaration
>   as IE = false.

Note: If any other browser were to use "JScript" this would pass, but since JScript is written by Microsoft I think you're safe. Another method is the navigator object, which you can pull the application name. Although some applications like to spoof this, so I believe the JScript is a bit more reliable.

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    alert('This is Internet Explorer!');
}
```

Edit: This was more to help users in detecting IE, not about directly answering the users question. Also, for users not wanting to use jQuery you could simple do document.getElementById('container').style.display = 'none'; -- Just figured I'd add this in since my post did mention "without using jQuery".

Comment: This is a fragile hack that relies on behavior that could easily be changed in a later version of IE. Using the user agent string would be better if you dont want to use Jquery.

Comment: @David: Agree, although there is really no perfect solution when using JavaScript, unless you used JavaScript with a combination of the IF tags. user agents get spoofed a lot, and this "hack" could be changed by Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

jquery makes this easy:

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
  $("#container").css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: @david: Thanks for reply. & how to stop IE from loading only ?

Comment: -1 even jQuery says: "We recommend against using this property, please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support)." source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: @galambalazs: He did not ask how to detect if the browser support a specific feature, but if it is IE. His answer is correct.

Comment: Do you know how jQuery gets browser? **"read from navigator.userAgent"** Do you know how navigator.userAgent starts in every browser (except opera)? Let me tell you. It starts with: Mozilla... **Rule no.1: BROWSERS LIE**

Comment: galambalazs: It checks if MSIE is contained in the string, which works. Obviously someone could spoof it.

Comment: I know it contains MSIE in "most" cases, but the thing i wanted to highlight is that user agent string cannot be trusted since the browser wars has started...

Comment: And the reason for that is the kind of usage we can see here. Browsers lie to get the content...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($.browser.msie) $("#container").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

### document.all

A very dirty option is using document.all which IE supports.

```
if(document.all){
    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
}
```

For some crazy reason, Chrome does support document.all, but checking for document.all returns false in it.

### navigator

Another option is to look at the navigator object.

```
if (navigator && navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
}
```

This could fail on browsers that spoof themselves as other browsers.

### comparison '*feature*'

You could also use a simple comparison.

```
if('\v' == 'v'){
    document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
}
```

I personally would not do this, but it is a neat detection to list.